# Nicer inverse symbol

Tags: tikz-pgf, symbols, nodes

In my diagram, I would like the operator to be centred, i.e. not be influenced by the inverse symbol. And preferably a smaller minus sign, while we are messing up latex anyway.

An except of tikz code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning} %relative positioning
\usetikzlibrary{calc} %complex positioning
\usetikzlibrary{shapes} %cloudy nodes


\newcommand{\inv}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[inner sep=-.2ex,font=\tiny] (a) {1};
\draw[-] (a) -- ($(a) + (-.3em,0)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=12pt, every node/.style={font=\footnotesize}]

\node[draw] {$\Phi^{\inv}$};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm not seeing what this should do better than `\Phi^{-1}`

Comment: It is a failed try to make the $Phi$ be centred  in the node. On top of it, it has a slightly smaller minus sign.

Comment: I'm afraid your code, as currently posted, doesn't compile: It crashes with an error message from the `pgfkeys` package, something about the key `/tikz/every node./style` not being recognized. Please fix the code. Thanks.

Comment: @Mico fixed node./styel => node/.style

Comment: The problem is `\node[draw] {$\Phi\makebox[0pt][l]{$^{\inv}$}$}` will center the symbol, but then the inverse rolls off the right edge.

Comment: $\Phi^\smash{-1}$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I end up doing:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning} %relative positioning

\newcommand{\inv}{\makebox[0pt][l]{$^{\raisebox{.2em}{\begin{tikzpicture}\draw[-] (0,0) -- (.2em,.0);\end{tikzpicture}}1}$}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=12pt, every node/.style={font=\footnotesize},op/.style={draw,minimum width=3em, minimum height=3em}]

\node[op] (phi inv) {$\Phi$\inv};
\node[op, right of=phi inv] (phi) {$\Phi$};


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Alternatively, if you see no problem with $^{-1}$ you can use:

```
\newcommand{\inv}{\makebox[0pt][l]{$^{-1}$}}
```

Comment: how is this even related to TikZ? if you just need a slightly bigger minus sign?

Comment: the makebox centers the phi inverse in the node, thus being in the same position as the phi forward